# Asynchron in useState

Tags: reactjs

My code is:

```js
<blink>
  const [thisButtomSelected, setThisButtomSelected] = useState({
    thisVal: 1111,
    thisIndex: 1111,
  })
   const onClick = e => {  
    setThisButtomSelected({ thisVal: e.currentTarget.value, thisIndex: e.currentTarget.id });
  }

  <li id="list" key={item.id}>
    <button
      value={item.value}
      id={index}
      className={isEqual(thisButtomSelected, { thisVal: item.value, thisIndex: index }) 
        ? 'button-selected' : 'button'
      }
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {item.displayValue}
    </button>
</li>
</blink>
```

Whenever I click the button in the app it makes `thisButtomSelected` always equal to the previous value.

In this case, is it not possible to change the button's style to what is selected?

I can't understand where the problem is?

Comment: dear @Ontolf can you provide more detail about the variables and components you are using? for example what is the item.id or value? also, what is index that you are using as id of the button?

Comment: @ShayanFaghani I am getting these variables from useQuery with map, is from apollo client

Comment: You're missing a closing `</li>`.

Comment: @sallf thank you for editing. I miss typed so code was without closing li

Answer (score 1):

the isEqual function you are using is not the native JavaScript function to use, instead, you can import Loadash and use it to compare two objects. to use the instruction would be like:

```
_.isEqual(object, other);
```

As I have mentioned before you have to install the loadash package and import it into your JS file.

Comment: Thank you. now is clear but I still have the issue that useState gives me previous value. I have 3 buttons: 1 2 3. When i am clicking on 1 console.log is showing 1111(is starting one), if i will click again i will get 1 from button 1.. ig i will click 2 i will get 1 from button 2. if i will click again i will get 2 from button 2.. so still unsolved

Comment: Where is your console.log? Consider adding it to your question.

Comment: Your code snippet is not enough for me to answer it. please provide the related information like where is your console.log. If you can you can simply make a little working piece of the project in codesandbox and share the link.

Comment: @Ontolf You can use this and alter the project itself like yours: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-cookies-7ldpw?file=/src/Components/SomeThing.js